# How To Flush A Websites Cache?

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, caching

This question is specific exclusively to Azure, in their portal.

I have a test site that I run in Azure wordpress; when I try to see updates I make, I don't see them.  Even if I flush my browser's cache, or access the site at a new location that's never been to the site, I do not see these changes.  My next attempt was to delete everything on the wordpress site, and re-upload the site.  This did nothing as well.

Based on my research, the only thing that I can figure is that Azure is keeping a copy of the pages somewhere in cache and this needs to be flushed.  I tried restarting the app service plan, and looked through the Portal, but never saw an option to flush the cache in settings.

Just a review:

1. I tried flushing the browser's cache.
2. I tried removing all the files and re-uploading.
3. I tried restarting the app service plan in the Azure portal.

Everything still shows the old design.

I can verify the new design exists by looking at `Appearance` then `Editor` php pages; the page source when the site loads is completely wrong (and strange since the page no longer exists anywhere on the server).

Comment: Is there a Wordpress plugin installed that might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following 2 options:

- set `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` to `0`, in **App settings** in your Azure Web Apps manage portal
- leverage the hint of [How to: Use a custom PHP runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure#how-to-use-a-custom-php-runtime) to modify the setting in `web.config` in your root directory of your application.
  We can use the Azure build-in PHP runtime instead our custom PHP runtime mentioned above, consider the following content in `web.config`:

  `<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
           <handlers>
              <add name="PHP-FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe"
                 resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
           </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`

Comment: @GaryLiuMSFT - thanks; in the app settings key-value, I set the key `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` to the value `0`.  I'll update the second one when I can get access to my FTP client - thanks!

Comment: @WashDCDev, glad to hear that, if it helps to you, you can mark it as answer, which will help other communities who facing the similar issue with you.

Comment: Key page - `front-page.php`.

Comment: The local cache app setting (not dynamic) could also cause this behavior https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache-overview