# Azure app service not using new/changed files

Tags: php, azure, caching, webjob

I have an PHP app running as an azure app service.

On the app service have a webjob that runs every 15 min and puts new images in a public folder. The problem is that these new images isn't being found when i try to view them in a browser. If I restart the web app however, they pop up.

I'm also running a file-based cache. the same thing seems to apply there. changes to the cache files are not being picked up until I restart the app.

Any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Could you share more details like the code you have written & the `web.config` file & what exactly error code you have got in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you refer the below thread from SO for more details.

[How To Flush A Websites Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503261/how-to-flush-a-websites-cache/)

As @Gary pointed out, you can try to set `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE` to `0`, in **App settings** in your Azure Web Apps manage portal.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will try this out first thing on tuesday when i'm back at work :)

Comment: Simply setting WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE to 0 in app settings, as you suggested, did the trick! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: would'nt that  hit the performance as the feature was introduced to reduce latency because of slow file read in azure.